# nginx ip_hash and IP block excluding

Tags: nginx

I am using upstream ip_hash in nginx. My configuration settings are as follows:

```
upstream example_upstream {
  ip_hash;
    server example1.com:80 max_fails=0 weight=50;
    server example2.com:80 max_fails=0 weight=50;
}
```

This configuration is working normally. But, I want to exclude some IP blocks out of this. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the help of nginx `geo` module:

On `http` level, you define the geo-block:

```
geo $my_upstream {
    default example_upstream;
    192.168.1.0/24 example1.com:80;
}
```

Then `$my_upstream` variable will contain a value suitable for `proxy_pass` statement, which you can use like this:

```
proxy_pass http://$my_upstream;
```

In addition you need the `upstream` block in your question.